# "She came to the city fleeing persecution in her home town."

Tags: gerunds, syntax, participles, adjuncts

I saw an interesting sentence due to play game;

> She came to the city ***fleeing*** persecution in her home town.

If talking about only meaning, I understand the sentence. She ran away to the city for avoiding persecution from her home town. (if it's not, please fix me.)

But that ***verb-ing*** form after *to + noun* clause is really unfamiliar to me.

What's the name of that gerund rule? Is that even categorized? Is there some kind of omitted word behind the scene like **that clause** does?

Comment: He came to the website asking a question.

Comment: @Astralbee Yeah it's related to the sentence but my question is the way of reading (understanding) and the structure itself.

Comment: 'She ran away to the city **to avoid** persecution...'

Comment: *She went to the city **seeking work***. Syntactically, the same kind of adverbial element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, *fleeing persecution in her home town* is called a ***gerund-participial clause***. In your sentence it functions as an adjunct. Not always easy to establish which kind of adjunct.  The most certain option is ***an adjunct of implicated reason***.

> She came to the city *(because she was)* fleeing persecution in her home town.

Note that your "to + noun phrase" does not *require* the gerund. It is not a structure, therefore, no need to look for a name for it. You could read your sentence as

> She came to the city [*in fear*].

By replacing *fleeing persecution in her home town* with *in fear*, you can see how the gerund-participial clause is independent from the rest of the sentence, not required by it.

Comment: Indeed the "to + noun phrase" is entirely irrelevant: you could equally say "she came _here_ fleeing persecution in her home town", or even just "she came fleeing persecution in her home town" and the "fleeing..." part would be the same structure with the same meaning.

Comment: *Gerund-participial* is a surprising term for me, because gerunds and participles serve different functions notwithstanding a superficial similarity. E.g. "Fleeing the city on the weekend is one of my guilty pleasures" -- unquestionably a gerund.

Comment: Moreover, the obvious Google search for `gerund-participial clause` finds several either explanations of the difference between gerunds and participles and several StackExchange pages using more or less the full term as used here. At first blush I'd infer that *gerund-participial* is a term more frequently encountered on this site than away from it. Is that a wrong inference?

Comment: @CynicallyNaive This site considers the CAGEL ([Cambridge Grammar of English Language](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language)) a reputable source. This book uses this term, so that explains why many users adopted it.

Comment: Interesting -- is this a US or NAm vs UK English distinction? As a native US speaker I've always seen a clear distinction taught. Gerunds act as nouns; participles act as adjectives or adverbs. I have seen cognate terms in other languages used differently. E.g.  *gerúndio* in Portuguese seems to mean participle.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive The book uses very often the term with many examples such as  _He went out **looking rather pleased with himself**._

Comment: Whoever downvoted could kindly explain why...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138310/discussion-between-cynicallynaive-and-fev).

Comment: Most important point: CAGEL merges gerunds and participles, and it's unclear to me how widespread this view is. (See: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2639).

Answer (score 2):

The example sentence:

> She came to the city fleeing persecution in her home town.

is grammatically valid and natural, a fluent speaker might well say it.

It could be rephrased as:

> [While]  fleeing persecution in her home town, she came to the city.

Or the original could be considered a reduced form of:

> > She came to the city **while** fleeing persecution in her home town.

I don't know a specific name for this sort of construction. Not every sentence pattern needs to have a special name.

A few somewhat similar uses of gerunds would be:

> - She went to the club looking for a new boyfriend.
> - She rented an apartment, avoiding the cost of a mortgage.
> - She came to wrok for is, operating a HAL-9000 computer
> - She came to my office, performing an audit for the IRS.
> - She came to the Remedy Center, performing Mozart's *Requiem*.
> - She came to be one of the city's best known artists, inventing an entirely new genre.

Comment: But this isn't a gerund, is it? It seems more like a participle -- hence you could easily substitute an adjective: "She came to the city *exhausted* from persecution...." Gerunds are more typically *-ing* used as nouns -- "Skiing is my favorite sport."

Comment: @CynicallyNaive The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) reads: "Traditional grammar makes a distinction within -ing forms between present participles and gerunds, a distinction that is not observed in such modern grammars as *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* and *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. " In the original sentence "fleeing" modifies "came" and thus functions adverbially. Whether you call it a gerund in that case is a matter of terminology with little effect on the grammar of the construction.